# Reference request: generalized linear (mixed) model for Dirichlet distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, dirichlet-distribution

Plenty of books about on GLMs for exponential families, but any good books or papers which study the Dirichlet distribution in particular?

Comment: Tell us why you are using the Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: The response variable is a discrete probability distribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Beta/Dirichlet Regression are not considered Generalized Linear Models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304538/why-beta-dirichlet-regression-are-not-considered-generalized-linear-models)

Comment: Ng, Tian and Tang, *Dirichlet and Related Distributions: Theory, Methods and Applications*

Comment: So why is it the Dirichlet distribution that is needed? Why not to estimate the parameters of a multinomial distribution?

Comment: `"The response variable is a discrete probability distribution."` Discrete as in the result of Bionomial experiments? If that's the case, then you actually want the Multinomial GLM.

Answer (score 1):

The book by Ludwig Fahrmeir
Gerhard Tutz:  "Multivariate Statistical
Modelling Based on
Generalized Linear Models
(Second Edition)" contain some references, but it seems to be mostly to use of the dirichlet distribution as a prior distribution in multinomial logistic models. There are many papers on Dirichlet regression, see https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rafiq_Hijazi/publication/228576713_Modelling_compositional_data_using_Dirichlet_regression_models/links/02e7e52e9cab9696f5000000.pdf  or  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rafiq_Hijazi/publication/265165887_Residuals_and_Diagnostics_in_Dirichlet_Regression/links/54054b8c0cf2c48563b13827.pdf .   But are these models GLM's?  see for instance [Why Beta/Dirichlet Regression are not considered Generalized Linear Models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304538/why-beta-dirichlet-regression-are-not-considered-generalized-linear-models)

Comment: What is the profit of using the Dirichlet distribution? Why are you not using, say, multinomial linear regression for the parameters of a categorical distribution itself?

Comment: Do the categorical distributions of the response seem to be irregular? Why are Poisson regression or binomial regression or something alike not suitable?

Comment: Please look through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression This is what I would start from.